# How to integrate janusgraph with an existing hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop, cluster-computing, janusgraph

I'm New to Big data and currently struggling to integrate janusgraph to an existing hadoop cluster. Can you please tell me how to do this or please provide a link to a resource.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're just getting started with JanusGraph, you should start with its official documentation located at http://docs.janusgraph.org/latest/

JanusGraph requires a storage backend. There are several supported [storage backends](http://docs.janusgraph.org/latest/storage-backends.html). Apache Hadoop, by itself, is not a storage backend for JanusGraph. The [Apache HBase storage backend](http://docs.janusgraph.org/latest/hbase.html) is most likely what you might have available.

Comment: Hi jason Thank you for the answer. I went through the documentation and i couldn't find a way to form a janusgraph cluster. Does a janusgraph cluster means just a janusgraph instance deployed with access to a hbase or cassandra cluster? Or can i configure a cluster of janusgraph/gremlin servers?

Comment: The storage and index backends are clustered. You can configure multiple Gremlin Servers to connect to the same backends, but they would not be clustered, that is the Gremlin Servers would not be aware of each other.

Comment: Thank you Jason. But for the graphs each node should have a unique id and it is generated by janusgraph. So if I run multiple instances of janusgraph pointing to the same backends, won't a data consistency issue arise because each server has no idea what the other server is doing.